# Detect the dates from text in text file. And then list them out using python

Tags: python, date, text-files

I have a text file that contains dates in the text. these dates are of format ("march 2016" or "march 2, 2016"). I wish to list them out. Can anybody help me with this?

this is my attempt

```
import re 
regex = '\s(\w+)\s(\d+\,)\s(\d+)' # this will match the form "str int, int" with open('./BACKGROUND OF THE SOLICITATION3.txt', 'r') as f: 
   text = f.read() 
all_dates = [' '.join(date) for date in re.findall(regex, text)] 
print all_dates
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This isn't a good place to post this question if you haven't given it a try and gotten stuck first.

Comment: lists them out as what exactly?

Comment: can you show what some of your input looks like?You may not need a regex at all if there is some pattern.

Comment: some text between the dates. These dates dont have a day. They have a day in it some times.                                                                                                         Example:  March 20,2013 is the best day of my life. But February 2013 is the worst month. I want to detect both March 20,2013 and February 2013 and list them.

Comment: The exact format of your input would be more useful.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham.. That is the exact format  and the example. And I used regex to detect one type.. But I couldn't detect both and list them

Comment: I tried this.. Now I'm missing year in the format ( March 1, 2013). I can only see the list of string and number.

Comment: I thought you only had two possibilities? Is there actually a space between `1, 2013`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = " I want to detect both March 20, 2013 and February 2013 3 and list them"

import  re

print(re.findall(r"([A-Z][a-z\s\d]+, \d+|[A-Z][a-z\s]+\d+)",s))
['March 20,2013', 'February 2013']
```